# Why prefix with jQuery's $ an internal detail?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Diving deeper into javascript and plugins in general, I am looking at some existing code - jQuery's tokenImput plugin.

This is really a more generic question - why is the internal "workhorse" object `TokenList` prefixed with jquery's `$` (i.e. why add it to jquery's name space)?

Here's a relevant illustration:

```
 // Expose the .tokenInput function to jQuery as a plugin
    $.fn.tokenInput = function(method) {
        ... this is the "public" entry point ...
        ... which, simplified, does something like this 
        ... to crank up the pluging functionality

        new $.TokenList(this, url_or_data_or_function, settings));
    };

    // TokenList class for each input
    $.TokenList = function(input, url_or_data, settings) {
        //
        // Initialization
        //

        // Configure the data source
        if ($.type(url_or_data) === "string" || $.type(url_or_data) === "function") {

        ... this is the encapsulation 
        ... that doesn't seem logical to belong to jQuery ...
```

Plugin is utilized via `tokenInput`:

```
$(element).tokenInput(svcUrl, {...});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the internal "workhorse" object prefixed with jquery's `$` (i.e. why add it to jquery's namespace)?

Because it fits there better than in the global namespace. It's a *jQuery* plugin does not work without jQuery, so this is reasonable and avoids global scope pollution.

One could as well hide the constructor in a closure (and export only the `$.fn.tokenInput` method), but by making it public it is possible to extend the class.

It is a [common practise](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/) to put the "static" parts of a plugin (public classes, global config objects, helper functions and similar) on the jQuery namespace, just as it is done with the "native" jQuery functions ([utilities](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/), or constructors like [`Event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) etc). However, it is good practise to name the static property the same as the prototype method, so `TokenInput` instead of `TokenList` here. Maybe it better would be `$.tokenInput.List`.

Comment: I guess it's not clear from how much code I shared, but `TokenList` is really all private implementation-specific logic. I failed to see any extension points or stand-alone value - I'll look again. But if for sake of learning we assume that it's all private logic, then wouldn't it make more sense to keep the function private to the plugin? How would author have achieved this (js syntax-wise)

Answer (score 0):

(Update: misunderstood the question as being about `tokenInput()` rather than `TokenList()`; replaced with a relevant answer.)

The jQuery object (`window.jQuery`,`$`) has two semantic purposes:

1. to be used as a function select DOM elements for reference or manipulation
2. to namespace its globally available members to keep them from interfering with other code

It appears that the writer of the plugin wanted the `TokenList()` function to be available globally; however, since it is not related to manipulating or referencing DOM elements, it didn't make sense to put it in, for example, `$.fn`, like `tokenInput()` is. But he still wanted it to be kept within jQuery's namespace.

This is how jQuery plugins are written; everything is attached to the jQuery object. If nothing else, this keeps the function within the jQuery namespace, so that it is less likely to trample on another plugin or function. This is not unique to this plugin. I've seen plenty that add extra mathematical functions, string manipulation methods, etc. directly to the jQuery object itself.

Comment: I think the question is about `$.TokenList = ` not the `$.fn` line.